# Spring Data JPA inheritance: Duplicate generator name warning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

I have a BaseEntity that every other Entity inherits from:

***BaseEntity.java:***

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "base_gen")
    private long id;

}
```

I then have two Entities User and Order that both inherit from BaseEntity whilst also having the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation:

***User.java:***

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "base_gen", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class User extends BaseEntity { ... }
```

***Order.java:***

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "base_gen", sequenceName = "order_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Order extends BaseEntity { ... }
```

However, I get *"Duplicate generator name base_gen"* warning on the console after running the app. **There are some workarounds** to fix this issue, but some of them use getter instead of `id` field and I am looking a cleaner approach. So, is there an proper approach to fic that issue?

I also thought to move `id` field from base to inherited classes, as shown below:

***User.java:***

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "base_gen", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class User extends BaseEntity { 
  
    @Id
    private long id;
}
```

But not sure if it is a proper way. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to share the same sequence (as you will now) then remove  `generator = "base_gen"` cempletly.

Comment: Actually I am trying to use a simple approach as much as possible and for this reason I used `id` field only in base class (to prevent repeating in inherited ones). For sequence, I also think similar. So, how can I fix this warning with a simplest solution (usage of id and sequences as less ass possible)?

Comment: Like I wrote, remove `baseGen` and let it autoresolve

Comment: I removed `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "base_gen")` line in `BaseEntity.java`, but it does not make any sense and still the same warning.

Comment: This is not what I wrote you to do. Also are you using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` ??

Comment: By the way, may it be related to being duplicate generator name in the database? If so, should I remove them via a migration script?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you post it as answer by code instead of words?

Comment: I wrote explicitly what you are supposed to remove.

Comment: I use `jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: validate` in application.properties.

Comment: Then you will have to modify your schema manually. Nothing can be done on entity mapping level since your schema is already "broken"\

Comment: Ok, could you please clarify me how can I do that?

Comment: You should remove autoincrement references to the sequence called "base_gen" from multiple tables if not all. Usually you dont need named sequences.

Comment: Do you mean only name parameters? Why do not post what you mean as code and still try to describe by words?

Comment: There is no need to. It is clear and robust already IMO

Comment: @Antonifissss I try to remove `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "base_gen")` from base entity. Then, update `@SequenceGenerator(name = "order_gen", sequenceName = "order_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)` and `@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_gen", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)` respectively. Now I get *"Schema-validation: missing sequence [`hibernate_sequence`]"* error. What about this approach and the cause of error? Any idea?

Comment: @Antonifissss Chico, any reply please?

Answer (score 0):

If you define `id` field in the base class, then *“Duplicate generator name x_base_gen”* error will be encountered.

To fix the problem, remove the `id` field from base class and add it to each of the inherited classes.